# Change same div class

Tags: jquery

This is my code:

```
<div class='silderitem'>
Some Content
</div>

<div class='silderitem'>
Another Some Content
</div>

<div class='silderitem'>
Again Another Some Content
</div>

<a class="next">next</a>
```

I want to change the next class when i click "next" using jquery. I tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var Slideshow=$('.slideritem');
    $(".next").click(function(){slideshow.next();return false});
</script>
```

Can anyone tell me the solution please ?

Comment: *"I want to change the next class when i click "next" using jquery."* what does this mean? What exactly are you trying to do? I suppose you want to some how iterate over the elements, but what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Define 'change'. Should you show the next item in queue, or transform it in some other ways?

Comment: you mistyped 'silderitem' in your html anyway. May that be the problem?

Comment: `Slideshow` and `slideshow` are different. But it won't solve your issue - what is "change the next class"?

Comment: sorry, i want to show the "some Content: first, then i click next show the "Another Some Content". Sorry for bad english..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to cycle through items, hiding the ones that aren't selected, something like this might work: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kLuff/3/)

css:

```
.silderitem { display: none }
.next { cursor: pointer }​
```

jquery:

```
$('.selected').show();

$(".next").click(function(){
    var selected = $('.selected');
    selected.removeClass('selected');
    selected.hide();

    var next = selected.next(".silderitem");
    if(next.length === 0) {
        next = $(".silderitem").first();
    }
    next.addClass('selected');
    next.show();
});​
```

html:

```
<div class='silderitem selected'>
Some Content
</div>

<div class='silderitem'>
Another Some Content
</div>

<div class='silderitem'>
Again Another Some Content
</div>

<a class="next">next</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, i want to hide others except the selected one. Is this possible ?

Comment: updated the answer to hide the elements that aren't "selected" / don't have focus

Comment: Thanks, this is what i want. Can you tell me how can i call the next function here ? so i can add image near slideritem and make it clickable to call next. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: no problem, you can just give any element a class of `next` and that will act the same as the next button, is that what you mean?